# not able to parse json array in php

Tags: php, json

I have this following php file that is supposed to loop through a json array and print the necessary information. But I am getting an error in browser which i don't know why it is shown."( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\wamp\www\bootstrap-dist\jsonpost.php on line 15". Can someone help me to solve this.

```
<?php
 $jArray ='{ "books":[{"id":"01",
                       "language": "Java",
                       "edition": "third",
                       "author": "Herbert Schildt"
                        },
                        {
                       "id":"07",
                       "language": "C++",
                       "edition": "second"
                       "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
                        }]
                    }'

    foreach ($jArray as $obj) { // error in this line
                 $ProductName = $obj['edition'];   
                 $ProductQuantity= $obj['language'];
                 echo   $ProductName+" "+$ProductQuantity;
             }

?>
```

Comment: Please use something like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your json strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the syntax error is because you forgot a semicolon after the JSON variable.

```
 ... 
        "E.Balagurusamy"
    }]
}'; // <-- there
```

And to parse it; use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$parsed = json_decode($jArray, true);
foreach ($parsed['books'] as $obj) {
    // ...
```

**EDIT:** Added `, true` to the `json_decode`, and also, your JSON has a syntax error.

```
"edition": "second", /* NOTE THE COMMA HERE */
"author": "E.Balagurusamy"
```

**EDIT 2:** Concatenating strings with `+` leads to 0. Use `.`.

```
echo $ProductName." ".$ProductQuantity;
```

Comment: even then i get this"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\bootstrap-dist\jsonpost.php on line 17" error